# sort multiple tables in jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

We have been using jquery tablesorter.js to sort the tables rows. But recently we have to split the table into multiple tables for the scroll bar to work with fixed columns. This is working fine but the sort functionality is gone. We cannot no more use tablesorter on multiple tables.

Can some body pls advise any solution for this using tablesorter.js or without that also?
HTML:

```
<table id="MainTbl">
<tbody>
 <tr>
    <td>
        <table id="tbl1">
            <thead>
                <tr class="A">
                    <th class="brkDwnDivComposite-first"> Caption </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr class="A">
                    <td><span title="A1">A1</span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="A">
                    <td><span title="A2">A2</span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="A">
                    <td><span title="A3">A3</span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="A">
                    <td><span title="A4">A4</span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="B">
                    <td><span title="Totals">Totals</span></td>
                 </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </td>
    <td style="width:660px">
        <div style="width: 660px; overflow-X: scroll">
            <table id="tbl2">
                <thead>
                    <tr class="A">
                        <th class="">08/19</th>
                        <th class="">08/21</th>
                        <th class="">08/26</th>
                        <th class="">09/09</th>
                        <th class="">09/23</th>
                     </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr class="A">
                        <td class="val">23</td>
                        <td class="val">1</td>
                        <td class="val">4</td>
                        <td class="val">45</td>
                        <td class="val">56</td>
                    </tr>
                     <tr class="A">
                        <td class="val">20</td>
                        <td class="val">21</td>
                        <td class="val">02</td>
                        <td class="val">03</td>
                        <td class="val">54</td>
                    </tr>
                     <tr class="A">
                        <td class="val">3</td>
                        <td class="val">2</td>
                        <td class="val">2</td>
                        <td class="val">1</td>
                        <td class="val">32</td>
                    </tr>

                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <table id="tbl3">
            <thead>
                <tr class="A">
                    <th class="A">Avg. grade</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

                <tr class="A">
                    <td class="B">0.45</td>    
                    <td class="B">0.236</td>
                    <td class="B">0.6</td>
                    <td class="B">0.98</td>
                    <td class="B">0.21</td>                              
                 </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Checkout this example**

```
$('table').tablesorter();

    // using a flag that prevents recursion - repeatedly calling this same function,
    // because it will trigger the "sortEnd" event after sorting the other tables.
    var recursionFlag = false;

    // bind to table sort end event on ALL tables
    $("table").bind("sortEnd",function(e, table) {

        // ignore if the flag is set
        if (!recursionFlag) {
            recursionFlag = true;

            // find other tables to resort (but not the current one)
            // the current sort is stored in "table.config.sortList"
            $('table').not(this).trigger("sorton", [ table.config.sortList ]);

            // reset recursion flag after 1 second... so you can't sort faster
            // than that or it won't trigger the other tables
            // you can adjust this value; it all depends on how much data needs
            // to be sorted in the tables. Run the tablesorter with "debug:true"
            // to find out the times needed to sort (but do it in IE as it is
            // the slowest browser)
            setTimeout(function(){ recursionFlag = false; }, 1000);

        }
    });
```

Comment: it is not working.. what is the table id to be passed to it??

Comment: No need to pass the id,here using common table tag name.

Comment: then if i click on the header in tbl2,only table tbl2 data is sorted. the respective columns of those rows in other tables are not re-ordered as per the sort.. is there any solution to it?

Comment: u have multiple table.when you click one table, on that particular table properties only work.

Comment: that is what..my data is single table view to see, but technically it divided across multiple tables and sort should work for all tables. Im looking for a solution to this.